# Cannot find project pages after publishing on server (Razor Pages)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a serious problem that I can not find the cause.

The project works well when running on localhost and without any problems.

But since I published in server it, it does not find some pages in the server .

Like the photos below

Look at this photo of the bar that can not find the path of the entered page. [image: Path when found on the publishing server]

This is a local host photo that has found the page well

[image: The path that is being developed is found correctly.]

This is my routing system in startup.cs

[image: Configure Startup.cs]

Server with plesk control panel

Is there a problem with the server?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tell me wherever you want me to send it to you.

My problem is not the code

The main problem is why only some screws are found.
But some are not found when the project is running on the server.

Comment: did you deploy to Plesk 'self-contained' of 'framework-dependent'? If you deployed 'framework-dependent' try 'self-contained'. You want to publish locally, remove the development appsettings and zip the rest. Copy the zip over to Plesk and unzip it in the root folder of youur site.

Comment: This app works well in Plesk
And all pages were found
Except for 5 of them.

When I publish in Plesk all pages are found and it worked fine

My problem is there are five pages that do not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late, but I had the same issue with Index page, and found out that in .csproj file there was something like this  and <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="Pages\Index.cshtml" /> and after removing those lines everything worked perfectly.